# Opening a Visio workflow interchange file (.vwi format) into a different site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a Visio workflow interchange file (.vwi format).

i am trying to open it into a different SharePoint site form the site for which i have created this file.

In this process i am getting the following error

[image]

Now i don't know what to do.

Can anyone help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .vwi format file only can be opened in the same site, in order to open these files we need same site in the SharePoint designer.